# How to install an application to different locations in a Websphere cluster

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have a Websphere cluster with 2 servers,and these two servers belong to 1 Node. Means that Server1=Node1:9080,Server=Node1:9081.

Now I want to install an application on this cluster,but there is only one application on the disk,like /opt/IBM/Websphere/xxx/myapp/myapp.war

can I install this application to different locations on these two servers?Like Server1:opt/IBM/Websphere/xxx/server1/myapp 
Server2:opt/IBM/Websphere/xxx/server2/myapp

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Why you want to install it into 2 diff locations? In general, you will not be able to install `same` application twice, as it will require different name, context-root, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the app will get copied from /opt/IBM/Websphere/xxx/myapp/myapp.war into the installation repository of the target server.